# Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in my apache2 server with php5

Tags: php, curl, apache2

I got this error when I run my project in which I use curl in windows7 environment.

```
  Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

I am use Apache2.2 and latest version of PHP and the directory is C:/Apache2; C:/PHP.
I set(remove ;) extension for curl in **php.ini** also check **php_curl.dll**, **ssleay32.dll** and **libeay32.dll** file are present in **C:/PHP** directory as well as **C:/windows/system32**.

Is there any configuration related problem or other problem??

Advanced thanks for any kinds of solution...

** My server is not wamp/xamp

Comment: check the configuration of PHP. Is there curl is enable? you can check configuration by php_info() function.

Comment: @OSSCubeSolution he already mentioned he checked the config and enabled the curl extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you did enable the curl extension in `php.ini` (the correct one). You should reboot your webserver. And check the output of `phpinfo();`

Comment: **Thanks**  I do it. phpinfo(); has no curl module.

Comment: @OSSCubeSolution You are just repeating my comment for you. Way to go. Big boy!!

Comment: @tlenss because you have post my comment in answer.